# Handlebars DOM Access

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I ant to know if there is a way to access the HTML DOM within a handlebars Helper function

e.g

```
 handlebars.registerHelper("helperName", function (data) {
  //getDocument
});
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript running in the browser or on a server (e.g. via Node.js)? What DOM do you want to access? The DOM of some existing page or the DOM of the HTML that handlebars is generating? Your question is very unclear. You should provide a [mcve] to supply some more context.

Comment: The Js is running on a node server